# Do the resources in your hands at end of mission count?

Tags: deep-rock-galactic

Does having resources (e.g. Enor Pearl) in hand (physically carrying) when boarding the ship at the end of a mission count toward the resources collected during the mission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [game Wiki](https://deeprockgalactic.fandom.com/wiki/Common_Misconceptions):

> All resources held in the player's inventory when entering the drop will count towards minerals, minerals mined, gold mined etc.
>
> The only two exceptions to this are that
>
> 1. Secondary objectives do not get completed when resources are not deposited.
> 2. Large minerals (such as Jadiz or Enor) do not count if not deposited.

Thus, the items you have to manually carry must be deposited into the mule to count.